# How to upgrade to the latest OpenSSH on CentOS

Tags: linux, centos, openssh

It seems that OpenSSH versions 5.4 thru 7.1 are vulnerable to an exploit that can trick the server into leaking the SSH keys that grant access to the service.

What is the best and safest way to upgrade to a patched version of OpenSSH on CentOS. Best being easiest and safest being not accidentally locking myself out of the remote server.

I do know that replacing the keys after the upgrade is crucial. Should I be using yum for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> exploit that can trick the server into leaking the SSH keys that grant access to the service.

No. It is a bug in client. The compromised server might get the keys from client and not the other way round.

The simplest way is to update `ssh_config` with `UseRoaming no`. Although the updates using `yum` is standard and does basically the same:

```
sudo yum update
```

The updates for CentOS [should be ready](https://lists.centos.org/pipermail/centos-announce/2016-January/021614.html) by now, so the above command should give you working update.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the update using yum, and afterwords restart the service. It keeps the old connection open even if you update and restart the service.

Comment: How to do it using yum, explaining that would be more helpful.

Comment: @serenesat Yes I should have mentioned that as well, assuming was a poor way to answer the question. Thanks for the advice.